# How can I use the init function only the first time?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I use this fetchItems function only the first time?

every time this setBrands function is used, it activates this fetchItems function and sets the starting values, I want it to be invoked only once

```
const [brands, setBrands] = useState({})
```

//brands is like this brands={CAT: "", RET: "", RTF: "", NW: ""}

```
useEffect(() => {
    const fetchItems = async () => {
      for (const b in brands) {
          brands[b] = await getCarts(b.id) //i am using like this brands[b] = await getCarts(b.id), but i think that is bad, i have to use setBrands()?
      }
    }
    fetchStoreItems()
  }, [brands])

return (
    <>
          <CartForm
            setBrands={setBrands}
          />
```

i am updating from CartForm the brands with this function setBrands

> note: if i delete the brand dependencies i get this error  warning
> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'brands'. Either
> include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Comment: are you getting error? or warning ?  if it's warning you can ignore that for your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`useEffect`'s dependency array affects when the callback gets called. If you want something to happen only during the mount, you need to have an empty dependency array.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // do your fetch here
}, [])
```

Sidenote:

```
useEffect(() => {
  // Gets called on first render
}, [])

useEffct(() => {
 // Gets called when value changes
}, [value])

useEffect(() => {
  // Gets called every render
})
```

Update:

```
const [brands, setBrands] = useState({})

useEffect(() => {
  ...
  for () {
    const data = await getCart(id)
    setBrands((prevBrands) => ({
      ...prevBrands,
      [key]: data
    }))
  }
  ...
}, [setBrands])
```

Comment: i am getting this error  warning  React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'brands'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Comment: i am using like this brands[b] = await getCarts(b.id), but i think that is bad, i have to use setBrands()?

Comment: There are a few issues with how you're trying to grab and save the data. #1: You're not updating the state correctly. You should use the `setBrands` function to update `brands` #2: You're attempting to update brands which you're also trying to update which will cause the effect to trigger again because it's a dependency

Comment: how can i update brands, if is an object like this brands={CAT: "", RET: "", RTF: "", NW: ""}?

Comment: I think you need to rethink how you're structuring your data. It is possible to update brands even if it's an object (refer to updated answer). The fact that brands being looped inside of the effect while updating it at the same time is a big no no.